# Application or object defined error (1004) When trying to merge cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm trying to merge some cells in a VBA programme but I keep running into an application or object defined error when trying to execute the code. The code runs perfectly when I set the merge range to defined cells but I need the merge range to be dynamic. The overall programme is building a database and the merge is the final step. I don't know if I'm explaining this well so I'll attach the code in hopes that you may understand! Thanks in advance :)

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Alpha = Sheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").End(xlDown)
Beta = Sheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -3)


Sheets("Jan").Range("Alpha:Beta").Merge
'APPLICATION OR OBJECT DEFINED ERROR HERE'


MsgBox "Your data has been added!"
Unload AddNewUF

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign two variable to range objects and expecting VBA to interpret them from text representations.

You are not SETting your range objects.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    dim Alpha as range, Beta as range

    SET Alpha = workSheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").End(xlDown)
    SET Beta = workSheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -3)

    Sheets("Jan").Range(Alpha, Beta).Merge '<~~ no error

    MsgBox "Your data has been merged! to " & alpha.mergearea.address(0,0, external:=true)
    Unload AddNewUF

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know this was even a thing so I'm going to do some more reading on it to try and understand it better. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Assigning a variable to a range object requires Set. It's kin'da like the difference between assigning a var a value or setting a pointer in C++. In the above I've set two range objects and used them as the start and stop with the operating range.